# Gene Set Enrichment Analysis

Tags: r, database, ontology, bioconductor

I have used the cummeRbund function *findSimilar()* to find the 10 most similar genes to the differentially expressed genes I identified using Cuffdiff. This used the Jensen-Shannon distance and produced a ranked ordered gene list which I now want to test for GO enrichment. The file looks like this:

```
"XLOC_007917" 0
"XLOC_008881" 0.00417099861122699 
"XLOC_017692" 0.0178758082512721 
"XLOC_008901" 0.0180682577435933 
"XLOC_014267" 0.0333227735282459 
"XLOC_013408" 0.0400392521794019 
"XLOC_013497" 0.0412541820119971 
"XLOC_010554" 0.0453928603025379 
"XLOC_000570" 0.0461264880687295 
"XLOC_010786" 0.0469577467848723
```

I first searched manually for GO terms for each of the most similar genes but I'd like to do a more robust analysis. I am trying to run GSEA, the Java application from Broad Institute.

I made my Ranked list file format (*.rnk) and now I have to choose a gene set database.

I am working on a sponge species so I can't use the database already provided.

How can I create my own gene sets database? What should it look like?

Answer (score 0):

My strategy is different after the assisted assembly. I extract the sequences of the newly discovered genes using Cufflinks, find the CDS, do BLAST, and get the GO terms. Another option is to use the genes that you have known IDs and use gProfiler to do the enrichment analysis. For example, you can get a free trial of Blast2go to do the analyses. You can install the databases locally and the Blast will be faster. You can do the enrichment analyses with Blast2go. You can also use install a instance of Galaxy and the get Blast2go from their tool shed repository.

Answer (score 0):

to make it work with GSEA, you need to have official human gene symbols as gene identifiers in the first column of your file. It is also a good idea to make sure that each gene appears only once in your ranked list. Also note that in the pre-ranked mode GSEA always sorts your input in descending order.